# NopCommerce 4.10 error while installing plugin

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, autofac, nopcommerce, nopcommerce-4.1

Hi have been following the [Pluralsight](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/nopcommerce-plugin-development/table-of-contents) Course on NopCommerce, but it is for the older version.

I have been trying to build the same functionality in NopCommerce 4.10

When I try to install the plugin, getting the error:

> No constructor was found that had all the dependencies satisfied.

No Tables are created in DB.
The error clearly states that these is a dependency that is not satisfied, but which is it? How do i satisfy it? I have an object context and 2 entities that are being registered with autofac and that is all i need if i'm right. What is the issue here?

Plugin Files:

**PromoImageRecord.cs**

```
using Nop.Core;

namespace Nop.Plugin.Widgets.PromoSlider.Domain
{
    public class PromoImageRecord: BaseEntity
    {
        public int PromoImageId { get; set; }
        public virtual int PromoSliderId { get; set; }
        public virtual string Caption { get; set; }
        public virtual string Url { get; set; }
        public virtual string FilePath { get; set; }
        public virtual int DisplayOrder { get; set; }

        public PromoSliderRecord PromoSlider { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**PromoSliderRecord.cs**

```
using Nop.Core;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Nop.Plugin.Widgets.PromoSlider.Domain
{
    public class PromoSliderRecord: BaseEntity
    {
        public PromoSliderRecord()
        {
            Images = new List<PromoImageRecord>();
        }


        public int PromoSliderId { get; set; }
        public virtual string PromoSliderName { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public virtual string ZoneName { get; set; }
        public virtual int Interval { get; set; }
        public virtual bool PauseOnHover { get; set; }
        public virtual bool Wrap { get; set; }
        public virtual bool KeyBoard { get; set; }

        public virtual List<PromoImageRecord> Images { get; set; }


    }
}
```

**PromoImageMap.cs**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using Nop.Plugin.Widgets.PromoSlider.Domain;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Nop.Plugin.Widgets.PromoSlider.Data
{
    public class PromoImageMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<PromoImageRecord>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PromoImageRecord> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("Some");
            builder.ToTable("PromoSlider_PromoImages");

            //Map the primary key
            builder.HasKey(m => m.PromoImageId);

            builder.Property(m => m.PromoSliderId);
            builder.Property(m => m.Caption);
            builder.Property(m => m.DisplayOrder);
            builder.Property(m => m.Url);

            builder.HasOne(x => x.PromoSlider).WithMany(x => x.Images).HasForeignKey(x => x.PromoSliderId).IsRequired();
        }
    }
}
```

**PromoSliderMap.cs**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using Nop.Plugin.Widgets.PromoSlider.Domain;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Nop.Plugin.Widgets.PromoSlider.Data
{
    public class PromoSliderMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<PromoSliderRecord>
    {
        public PromoSliderMap()
        {

        }

        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PromoSliderRecord> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("PromoSlider_PromoSliders");
            builder.HasKey(x => x.PromoSliderId);

            builder.Property(m => m.PromoSliderName);
            builder.Property(m => m.ZoneName);
            builder.Property(m => m.Interval);
            builder.Property(m => m.KeyBoard);
            builder.Property(m => m.PauseOnHover);
            builder.Property(m => m.Wrap);

        }
    }
}
```

**PromoSliderObjectContext.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Nop.Core;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Nop.Data;

namespace Nop.Plugin.Widgets.PromoSlider.Data
{
    public class PromoSliderObjectContext: DbContext, IDbContext
    {
        // (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB
        public PromoSliderObjectContext(string connString): base(SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(new DbContextOptionsBuilder(), connString).Options)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new PromoSliderMap());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new PromoImageMap());
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        public string CreateDatabaseInstallationScript()
        {
            return this.Database.GenerateCreateScript();
        }

        public void Install()
        {
            var context = new PromoSliderObjectContext(@"Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=NopCommercePractice11;Integrated Security=True");
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        public void UnInstall()
        {
            //this.Database.drop
        }

        DbSet<TEntity> IDbContext.Set<TEntity>()
        {
            return base.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        int IDbContext.SaveChanges()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        string IDbContext.GenerateCreateScript()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        IQueryable<TQuery> IDbContext.QueryFromSql<TQuery>(string sql)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        IQueryable<TEntity> IDbContext.EntityFromSql<TEntity>(string sql, params object[] parameters)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        int IDbContext.ExecuteSqlCommand(RawSqlString sql, bool doNotEnsureTransaction, int? timeout, params object[] parameters)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void IDbContext.Detach<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

**PromoSliderDependencyRegistrar.cs**

```
using Autofac;
using Nop.Core.Configuration;
using Nop.Core.Infrastructure;
using Nop.Core.Infrastructure.DependencyManagement;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Nop.Web.Framework.Mvc;
using Nop.Data;
using Nop.Plugin.Widgets.PromoSlider.Domain;
using Nop.Core.Data;
using Autofac.Core;

namespace Nop.Plugin.Widgets.PromoSlider.Data
{
    public class PromoSliderDependencyRegistrar : IDependencyRegistrar
    {
        private const string CONTEXT_NAME = "nop_object_context_promo_slider";

        public int Order => 1;

        public void Register(ContainerBuilder builder, ITypeFinder typeFinder, NopConfig config)
        {
            builder.RegisterType<PromoSliderObjectContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            builder.RegisterType<EfRepository<PromoSliderRecord>>()
                .As<IRepository<PromoSliderRecord>>()
                .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<IDbContext>(CONTEXT_NAME))
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<EfRepository<PromoImageRecord>>()
                .As<IRepository<PromoImageRecord>>()
                .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<IDbContext>(CONTEXT_NAME))
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        }
    }
}
```

**PromoSliderPlugin.cs**

```
using Nop.Core.Plugins;
using Nop.Plugin.Widgets.PromoSlider.Data;
using Nop.Services.Cms;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Nop.Plugin.Widgets.PromoSlider
{
    public class PromoSliderPlugin: BasePlugin, IWidgetPlugin
    {
        private PromoSliderObjectContext _context;

        public PromoSliderPlugin(PromoSliderObjectContext contenxt)
        {
            _context = contenxt;
        }

        public string GetWidgetViewComponentName(string widgetZone)
        {
            return "WidgetsPromoSlider";
        }

        public IList<string> GetWidgetZones()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void Install()
        {
            _context.Install();
            base.Install();
        }

        public override void Uninstall()
        {
            _context.UnInstall();
            base.Uninstall();
        }
    }
}
```

**Notes.txt:-**

```
Important points when developing plugins


- All views (cshtml files) and web.config file should have "Build action" set to "Content" and "Copy to output directory" set to "Copy if newer"

- When you develop a new plugin from scratch, and when a new class library is added to the solution, open its .csproj file (a main project file) in any text editor and replace its content with the following one

<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework> 
  </PropertyGroup>  
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>..\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Widgets.PromoSlider</OutputPath>
    <OutDir>$(OutputPath)</OutDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>..\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Widgets.PromoSlider</OutputPath>
    <OutDir>$(OutputPath)</OutDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <!-- This target execute after "Build" target -->
  <Target Name="NopTarget" AfterTargets="Build">
    <!-- Delete unnecessary libraries from plugins path -->
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.proj" Properties="PluginPath=$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(OutDir)" Targets="NopClear" />
  </Target>
</Project>

Replace “PLUGIN_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY” in the code above with your real plugin output directory name. 

It’s not required. But this way we can use a new ASP.NET approach to add third-party references. It was introduced in .NET Core. Furthermore, references from already referenced libraries will be loaded automatically. It’s very convenient
```

**plugin.json:-**

```
{
  "Group": "Widgets",
  "FriendlyName": "Promo Slider",
  "SystemName": "Widgets.PromoSlider",
  "Version": "1.0",
  "SupportedVersions": [ "4.10" ],
  "Author": "Any",
  "DisplayOrder": 1,
  "FileName": "Nop.Plugin.Widgets.PromoSlider.dll",
  "Description": "This plugin allows you to change the contents of main page slider"
}
```

Can someone please help!

Answer (score 2):

I'm also trying to create a NopCommerce 4.10 plugin from the PluralSight tutorial course and ran into the same error. What solved it for me, was to include a `PluginDbStartup.cs` file. Take an example from the `Nop.Plugin.Pickup.PickupInStore` and the `Nop.Plugin.Shipping.FixedByWeightByTotal` plugins, they have implemented it correctly for 4.10.

My implementation of the plugin is available on https://github.com/florianock/NopCommerce_PromoSlider